# How to prevent logback/slf4j from parsing a new line character

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm using logback with SLF4j for logging in my application. I have a string that contains a new line character. It is part of the string value but doesn't signify a new line. When I print the string, logback prints it in a new line. How to prevent this ?

Code:

```
String str = "george\nmason"
logger.info(str);
```

Logback pattern:

```
<pattern>[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%5p] [%X{sid}] [%-20C{0} %25M]:[%-4L] - %m%n</pattern>
```

Expected:

```
[19 Feb 2015 20:19:27] [ INFO] [] [myClass myMethod]:[52  ] - george\nmason
```

Actual Output:

```
[19 Feb 2015 20:19:27] [ INFO] [] [myClass myMethod]:[52  ] - george
mason
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a [`replace`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace) option to your pattern in order to replace any new-line characters from the message with something else, such as a space:

```
%replace(%m){'\n', ' '}
```

In your case, you'd like to replace `\n` with `\\n`:

```
<pattern>[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] [%5p] [%X{sid}] [%-20C{0} %25M]:[%-4L] - %replace(%m){'\n', '\\n'}%n</pattern>
```

Comment: is this replacement expensive ?

Comment: My strack traces now have \n. Is there a way to fix this ? This is not really concern but good to avoid in this case.

Comment: That's actually a separate question. :)

Comment: They came up because of this replacement. Otherwise they were good. :)

Comment: Your original question asks how to prevent new-lines in messages. Your new question is how to show stacktraces with new-lines. It's related but different. The `replace` pattern is applied to the message, so if your stacktraces have \n replaced, it's likely because they're logged within the message by your application. You'd either have to modify your application to separate the exception from the message, or modify the `replace` option's regex so that it replaces only new-lines that aren't part of exceptions.

Comment: thanks! posted a follow-up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652640/logback-pattern-do-replace-if-message-doesnt-contain-a-word